# SSH sends different keys with this same configuration

Tags: linux, ssh

For some reason I can't log in to the server with SSH. I wrote to the server administrator and he told me that connection is blocked by sshguard. In addition, he sent me a list of my login attempts ( `sudo grep publickey\ for\ <myusername> /var/log/auth` command output). It looked like this:

```
.
.
.
May 12 21:38:16 boss sshd[3003]: Failed publickey for <myusername> from
<myip> port 24057 ssh2: RSA
SHA256:hqddgd...VHhFM
May 12 21:38:16 boss sshd[3003]: Failed publickey for <myusername> from
<myip> port 24057 ssh2: RSA
SHA256:1NwYXJ66...+U5MqJ0
May 12 21:38:21 boss sshd[3003]: Accepted publickey for <myusername> from
<myip> port 24057 ssh2: RSA
SHA256:A6uQ/jb...I9UjXzc
May 12 21:39:29 boss sshd[3151]: Failed publickey for <myusername> from
<myip> port 23837 ssh2: RSA
SHA256:hqddgd...VHhFM
May 12 21:39:30 boss sshd[3151]: Failed publickey for <myusername> from
<myip> port 23837 ssh2: RSA
SHA256:1NwYXJ66...+U5MqJ0
.
.
.
```

Whenever I tried to log in I sent keys that had checksums in order: hqddgd...VHhFM, 1NwYXJ66...+U5MqJ0, A6uQ/jb...I9UjXzc. The third time my connection was always accepted. I don't know if this is a coincidence, but I have exactly three keys in the ~/.ssh/ directory. In addition, the ~/.ssh/config file looks like this:

```
Host <server to which I want to log in>
    HostName <nice domain>
    User <myusername>
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/<myusername>

Host <another server>
    HostName <nice domain>
    User <another username>
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/<another username>
```

Why is this happening? Why SSH sends different keys with this same configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add this line to your configuration file:

```
IdentitiesOnly=yes
```